# Table not reflowing when row added dynamically

Tags: javascript, reflow

I'm adding a row to a table dynamically. The problem is that the browser does not seem to reflow properly when it's added, and all the data goes into the first cell of the new row, rather than being spread across it. This sounds a bit odd, so I've made test case, below. As far as I can tell, the row is being added properly to the correct place, and this happens in all browsers (Chrome 36.0, FF 31.0, IE 11.0), so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table management page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var string = "<tr><td>Extra value 1</td><td>Extra value 2</td></tr>";

        function addrow() {
            var parser=new DOMParser();
            var xml=parser.parseFromString(string,'text/xml');
            var rows = xml.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            document.getElementById('table_data').appendChild(rows[0]);
        } 

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th></tr>
        </thead> 
        <tbody id="table_data">
            <tr><td>Value 1</td><td>Value 2</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type='button' onclick='addrow();' value='Add a row' />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inserRow and insertCell methods

```
 function addrow() {
            var parser=new DOMParser();
            var xml=parser.parseFromString(string,'text/xml');
            var row=document.getElementById('table_data').insertRow();

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

// Add some text to the new cells:
cell1.innerHTML = "Extra value 1";
cell2.innerHTML = "Extra value 2";

        }
```

EDIT - By using createElement

```
 function addrow() {
            var parser=new DOMParser();
            var xml=parser.parseFromString(string,'text/xml');
            var rows = xml.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var trs= document.createElement('tr');
            var td1=document.createElement('td');
            td1.innerHTML='Value 1';
            trs.appendChild(td1);
            var td2=document.createElement('td');
            td2.innerHTML='Value 2';
            trs.appendChild(td2);
            document.getElementById('table_data').appendChild(trs);
        }
```

Comment: But why does my method not work? I already have a perfectly formed element. Why do I have to break it down into bits?

Comment: @Chris Your method can also work, but then you need to create the tr and td dynamically using document.createElement('tr'). In this way javascript knows its appending actual row to table and not anything else.

Comment: But that doesn't use the xml string at all. It just creates rows and then ignores it for the rest of the script. I know I can do it all these other ways, but I still don't see why my method doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if use JQuery , it much easier:

```
var string = "<tr><td>Extra value 1</td><td>Extra value 2</td></tr>";

function addrow() {
    $('#table_data').append($(string));

}
```